# js2xmlparser custom XML body

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to create a XML body with js2xmlparser module which looks like this:

```
<methodCall>
    <methodName>Some method name</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>Some value</string>
            </value>
            <value>
                <string>Some value</string>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

my object for parsing:

```
var obj = {
   "methodName": "TsaInfoHandler.getIppCert",
   "params": {
      "param": [
        {value: { string: this.projectPartnerNumber } } ,
        {value: { string: this.projectPartnerKey } } ,
     ]
   }
 }
```

but the output I get is:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>Some method name</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>Some value</string>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>Some value</string>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

I just want it so that `param` does not repeat after each `value` but rather encapsulate all the `value` together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you make param an object where its key is value as an array?

param: { value: [ { ... }, { ... } ]  }